# How to extract query parameters from wordpress permalinks to be used in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, query-string

What is the best way to extract query parameters from Wordpress urls in javascript. Urls are pure permalinks without "?".
The worpdress site is multilinugual (WPML), so the will be url varations. The same value has to be exctracted from different permalink equivalents.

example.com/location/1

example.com/de/lage/1

Comment: Get the URL value as a string and `split()` it by `/` to get an array of the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `window.location.search` get query string.

You need `window.location.pathname` to get all data after first slash.

For example for this page:

```
> console.log(window.location.pathname);
/questions/43932650/how-to-extract-query-parameters-from-wordpress-permalinks-in-javascript/43932720#43932720

> console.log(window.location.search);
'' // becase there is no query string
```

After that you have to parse query string. You need this:

```
window.location.search.substr(1).split('&').map(function (value) {
  var data = value.split('=');
  return {
    param : data[0],
    value : data[1]
  }
});
```

For this tring

```
https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript+location+get+parameters&oq=javascript+location+get+parameters&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6512j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

the result will be:

[image]

Now, you need something similar to parse pathname. I don't know specific of how this string is built from WP side so I can't help there.

Comment: Thank you, In my case there will be never query strings like ?q=1&param=1

, only premalinks /q/1/param/1

Comment: Ye, I also provided the information how to get the string after `host:port`. Here is it `window.location.pathname`. I also said that you have to think about it by yourself based on information that I gave to you about query string.

Answer (score 0):

I ened with php solution:

```
   <?php  if( array_key_exists( 'location' , $wp_query->query_vars ) ):
       $l= $wp_query->query_vars["location"];?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.qloc="<?php echo $l;?>";
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
You can get all params as an array:

example URL: example.com?discount_code=1234

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

if(urlParams && urlParams.has('discount_code'))
{
   alert(urlParams.get('discount_code'));
}
```

[Details of browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams)

**Method 2:**
[View This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1535357)